# A tela carregada está correta mas os dados são salvos em outra tabela do BD

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

no site da empresa, estamos fazendo alguns testes com agendamentos. Problema é que embora esteja carregando a tela correta no site (o formulário de agendamento), os dados que o cliente digita, estão sendo salvos na tabela de orçamento. 
Deixando claro que não fui eu quem fiz o sistema, nem o front-end, estou apenas dando manutenção e inserindo mais funcionalidades. 
Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser? É o CodeIgniter e MySQL

Minha view

```
<section class="section_mod-d border-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 wow bounceInLeft txt-center" data-wow-duration="1s">
            <h1 class="ui-title-block">AGENDE O SERVIÇO</h1>
        </div>
      <!-- end col -->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

            <style>
                .panel-tabs {
                    position: relative;
                    bottom: 30px;
                    clear:both;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
                }

                .panel-tabs > li {
                    float: left;
                    margin-bottom: -1px;
                }

                .panel-tabs > li > a {
                    margin-right: 2px;
                    margin-top: 4px;
                    line-height: .85;
                    border: 1px solid transparent;
                    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
                    color: #ffffff;
                }

                .panel-tabs > li > a:hover {
                    border-color: transparent;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    background-color: transparent;
                }

                .panel-tabs > li.active > a,
                .panel-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
                .panel-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
                    color: #fff;
                    cursor: default;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
                    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
                    border-radius: 2px;
                    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .23);
                    border-bottom-color: transparent;
                }
                /*========================================  MODIFICAÇÕES TEMPORARIAS ===========================*/
                .panel-primary > .panel-heading {
                    color: #ffffff;
                    background-color: #486d8b !important;
                    border-color: #355671 !important;
                }
                .panel-title{color:#fff !important;}
                .panel-primary{border-color: #355671 !important; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 40px;}
            </style>



                <div class="col-md-7 wow bounceInRight" data-wow-duration="1s">
                    <div class="section-list-block">
                        <ul class="list-block list-unstyled">
                            <?php foreach($textoBlocos as $key => $texto) { ?>
                            <li class="list-block__item"> 
                                <a class="list-block__link">                                        
                                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/icon_cad_' . ($key + 1) . '.png'); ?> " alt="icone 1" style="float: left; padding: 0px 25px 0px 0px;">
                                    <div class="list-block__title"><?php echo $texto->complemento; ?></div>
                                    <div class="list-block__info"><?php echo $texto->valor; ?></div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>                            
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 margin_g form_cadastro">                        
                    <?php echo form_open('cadastro/pedidos', array('id' => 'formCadastro', 'class' => 'bounceInLeft form-b', 'data-wow-duration' => '2s')); ?>
                        <div class="form-request__text form-b col-sm-12">Faça seu Agendamento</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6"><h6>* campos obrigatórios</h6></div><br clear=all/>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input class="form-control form-b" type="text" placeholder="* Nome Completo" name="nome" id="nome" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input class="form-control form-b" type="mail" placeholder="* email" name="email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input class="form-control form-b" type="text" id="celular" placeholder="* Celular" name="celular">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <select name="estado" id="estado" class="form-control form-b" required>
                                <option value="" class="option_cad"> ESTADO</option>
                                <?php foreach($estados as $estado) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $estado->id; ?>" class="option_cad"><?php echo $estado->nome; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <select name="cidade" id="cidade" class="form-control form-b" required>
                                <option value="" class="option_cad">* CIDADE</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input class="form-control form-b" type="text" placeholder="* Bairro" name="bairro" id="bairro" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <select name="categoria" id="categoria" class="form-control form-b" required>
                                <option value="" class="option_cad">* CATEGORIA</option>
                                <?php foreach($listaCategorias as $categoria) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $categoria->id_categoria; ?>" class="option_cad"><?php echo $categoria->categoria; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <select name="subcategoria" id="subcategoria" class="form-control form-b" required>
                                <option value="" class="option_cad">* SUB CATEGORIA</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12"><h6>Entre quais dias você quer o serviço agendado?</h6></div><br clear=all/>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input class="form-control form-b" type="text" id="data_de" placeholder="* De" name="data_de">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input class="form-control form-b" type="text" id="data_ate" placeholder="* Até" name="data_ate">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12"><h6>Em qual horário?</h6></div><br clear=all/>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input class="form-control form-b" type="text" placeholder="* Horário" name="horario" id="horario" required>
                        </div>                            
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input class="form-control form-b" type="text" placeholder="* Descrição do Serviço" name="descricao" id="descricao" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-second btn-effect">Agendar</button>
                        </div>
                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row margin-g">
                <div class="section-default  border-bottom_thin wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 txt-center">
                                <h2 class="ui-title-block">Por que anunciar na sossegue</h2>
                                <div class="decor-1 decor-1_mod-a decor-1_mod-d"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <ul class="advantages advantages_mod-a list-unstyled">
                                    <li class="advantages__item clearfix">
                                        <i class="icon flaticon-rocketship4"></i>
                                        <div class="advantages__inner">
                                            <div class="advantages__name"><?php echo $config['vantagens_left_complemento']; ?></div>
                                            <div class="advantages__text"><?php echo $config['vantagens_left']; ?></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="advantages__item clearfix">
                                        <i class="icon flaticon-badges3"></i>
                                        <div class="advantages__inner">
                                            <div class="advantages__name"><?php echo $config['vantagens_center_complemento']; ?></div>
                                            <div class="advantages__text"><?php echo $config['vantagens_center']; ?></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="advantages__item clearfix">
                                        <i class="icon flaticon-house158"></i>
                                        <div class="advantages__inner">
                                            <div class="advantages__name"><?php echo $config['vantagens_right_complemento']; ?></div>
                                            <div class="advantages__text"><?php echo $config['vantagens_right']; ?></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div><!-- end col -->
                        </div><!-- end row -->
                    </div><!-- end container -->
                </div><!-- end section-default -->

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<?php if($this->session->flashdata('msg')) { ?>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalCadastro" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="margin-top: 80px">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('login'); ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Meu Controller (que não por vontade minha, tem coisa de Model no meio)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Agendamentos extends MY_Front {

    public function agendar() {
        if($this->form_validation->run('agendamentos/agendar')) {


                $agendamento = array(
                    'nome'              => $this->input->post('nome'),
                    'email'             => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'telefone'          => $this->input->post('telefone'),
                    'celular'           => $this->input->post('celular'),
                    'id_cidade'         => $this->input->post('cidade'),
                    'bairro'            => $this->input->post('bairro'),
                    'id_subcategoria'   => $this->input->post('subcategoria'),
                    'data_de'           => convertData($this->input->post('data_de')), 
                    'data_ate'          => convertData($this->input->post('data_ate')),
                    'horario'           => $this->input->post('horario'),
                    'descricao'         => $this->input->post('descricao'),
                    'data_agendamento'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                );


                $idAgendamento = $this->superModel->insert('agendamento', $agendamento);


                $this->db->select('cidade.nome AS cidade');
                $this->db->join('cidade', 'cidade.id = agendamento.id_cidade');
                $this->db->where('id_agendamento', $idAgendamento);
                $endereco = $this->db->get('agendamento')->row();

                if($endereco) {
                    $data['cidade'] = $endereco->cidade;
                }

                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            //    $this->enviaEmailAgendamento($data);

        $this->layout->view('confirmacao-agendamento', $this->data);
        } else {

            $clausulas = array(
            'order' => array(
                array(
                    'campo' => 'ordem',
                    'valor' => 'ASC'
                )
            )
        );

            $clausulas['order'] = array(
            array(
                'campo' => 'categoria'
            )
        );

        $this->data['listaCategorias'] = $this->superModel->select('categoria', $clausulas);


        $this->data['estados'] = $this->superModel->select('estado');
            $data = array(
                'select' => 'valor, complemento',
                'condicoes' => array(
                    array(
                        'campo' => 'campo',
                        'valor' => 'cadastro_bloco',
                        'like' => 'after',
                        'escape' => true
                    )
                ),
                'order' => array(
                    array(
                        'campo' => 'campo'
                    )
                )
            );

            $this->data['textoBlocos'] = $this->superModel->select('configuracoes', $data);

            insertTag('js', 'jquery.maskedinput.min.js', $this->data);
            $this->layout->view('agendamentos', $this->data);
        }

    }


    private function enviaEmailAgendamento($data) {
        $configEmail = $this->superModel->getRow('config_email');
        $this->load->library('email');

        $mensagem = '<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="pt-br">
                <head>
                    <title>Sossegue - Solicitação de serviço</title>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
                    <style type="text/css">
                        /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
                        #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" message */
                        .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
                        .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing */
                        body, table, td, a{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;} /* Prevent WebKit and Windows mobile changing default text sizes */
                        table, td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;} /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up */
                        img{-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;} /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */
                        /* RESET STYLES */
                        body{margin:0; padding:0;}
                        img{border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
                        table{border-collapse:collapse !important;}
                        body{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;}
                        /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
                        .appleBody a {color:#68440a; text-decoration: none;}
                        .appleFooter a {color:#999999; text-decoration: none;}
                        /* MOBILE STYLES */
                        @media screen and (max-width: 525px) {
                            /* ALLOWS FOR FLUID TABLES */
                            table[class="wrapper"]{
                              width:100% !important;
                            }
                            /* ADJUSTS LAYOUT OF LOGO IMAGE */
                            td[class="logo"]{
                              text-align: left;
                              padding: 20px 0 20px 0 !important;
                            }
                            td[class="logo"] img{
                              margin:0 auto!important;
                            }
                            /* USE THESE CLASSES TO HIDE CONTENT ON MOBILE */
                            td[class="mobile-hide"]{
                              display:none;}
                            img[class="mobile-hide"]{
                              display: none !important;
                            }
                            img[class="img-max"]{
                              max-width: 100% !important;
                              height:auto !important;
                            }
                            /* FULL-WIDTH TABLES */
                            table[class="responsive-table"]{
                              width:100%!important;
                            }
                            /* UTILITY CLASSES FOR ADJUSTING PADDING ON MOBILE */
                            td[class="padding"]{
                              padding: 10px 5% 15px 5% !important;
                            }
                            td[class="padding-copy"]{
                              padding: 10px 5% 10px 5% !important;
                              text-align: center;
                            }
                            td[class="padding-meta"]{
                              padding: 30px 5% 0px 5% !important;
                              text-align: center;
                            }
                            td[class="no-pad"]{
                              padding: 0 0 20px 0 !important;
                            }
                            td[class="no-padding"]{
                              padding: 0 !important;
                            }
                            td[class="section-padding"]{
                              padding: 50px 15px 50px 15px !important;
                            }
                            td[class="section-padding-bottom-image"]{
                              padding: 50px 15px 0 15px !important;
                            }
                            /* ADJUST BUTTONS ON MOBILE */
                            td[class="mobile-wrapper"]{
                                padding: 10px 5% 15px 5% !important;
                            }
                            table[class="mobile-button-container"]{
                                margin:0 auto;
                                width:100% !important;
                            }
                            a[class="mobile-button"]{
                                width:80% !important;
                                padding: 15px !important;
                                border: 0 !important;
                                font-size: 16px !important;
                            }
                        }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                <div align="center" style="padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="wrapper">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;" class="logo">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100" align="left"><a href="'.base_url().'" target="_blank"><img alt="Logo Sossegue" src="'.base_url("assets/img/logo_mod-a.png").'" width="130" style="display: block;" border="0"></a></td>
                                                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="400" align="right" class="mobile-hide">
                                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="right" style="padding: 0 0 5px 0; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; text-decoration: none;"><span style="color: #666666; text-decoration: none;"><a href="'.base_url().'" target="_blank">SOSSEGUE</a><br>Sua vida mais tranquila</span></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 30px 15px 70px 15px;" class="section-padding">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="responsive-table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 0 0 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666;" class="padding-copy">Olá, um novo cliente está precisando de agendamento de serviços. Cheque os agendamentos na área administrativa e entre em contato.</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-button-container">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 0 0 0;font-size: 16px; line-height: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666;" class="padding-copy">

                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </body>
                </html>';

        $emailEnviado = $this->email
            ->from($configEmail->username, 'Sossegue')
            ->to('contato.sossegue@gmail.com, contato@sossegue.com.br')
            ->subject("Sossegue - Solicitação de agendamento")
            ->message($mensagem)
            ->send();

    }


}
```

Comment: Mas porque o action dele chama outra pagina que não é essa do agendamento?

Comment: @AndréBaill você se refere a página de confirmação?

Comment: O Action esta apontando para cadastro/pedidos, sendo assim, precisa dar uma olhada no controller cadastro e no metodo pedidos, dai sim da para saber!

Comment: Conseguiu ajusar?

Comment: @AndréBaill muito obrigada, bobeira que deixei passar.

Comment: Por nada, a disposição